# The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"settings"} was not handled by any navigator. Do you have a screen named 'settings'?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

When i'm trying to navigate from  `'review'` to `'settings'` i got this error:

The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"settings"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'settings'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production.

```
   review = () => {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator >
        <Stack.Screen 
            name="review" 
            component={ReviewScreen}
            options={{
              headerTitle: 'review jobs',
              headerRight: () => (
                <Button
                  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('settings')}
                  title="settings"
                />
              ),
            }} 
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="settings" component={SettingScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }

render() {
    return ( 
<NavigationContainer independent={true} >
  <Tab.Navigator>
    <Tab.Screen name="deck" component={DeckScreen}  />
    <Tab.Screen name="map" component={MapScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="review" component={this.review} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
     );
}
```

I'm using react navigation with this versions:
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.3.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.2.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.18",

Comment: I'm also used navigation.navigate('review', { screen: 'settings' })